# RuntimeError: variable_scope module_1/ was unused but the corresponding name_scope was already taken. How can i fix it

Tags: python, tensorflow, text, nlp, elmo

i got this problem with elmo and tensorflow and i wanna fix it without downgrade. what should i do

```
`**CODE**
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf
#Elmo
elmo = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", trainable=True)

# Provide input tensor and create embeddings
input_tensor = ["my birthday is the best day of the year"]
embeddings_tensor = elmo(input_tensor, signature="default", as_dict=True)["elmo"]
* here i got the problem *
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    embeddings = sess.run(embeddings_tensor)
    print(embeddings.shape)
    print(embeddings) 
`
```

Comment: please post the same error (from the title) into a paragraph below the code.

Answer (score 1):

`hub.module()` is only compatible with `TF 1.x` and [deprecated](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/model_compatibility#compatibility_of_hubmodule) from using in `TF 2.x`. In place of that we can use `hub.load()` in `TF 2.x` code.

You can run your code without error by doing following changes in `TF 2.8` (or in TF 2.x).

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf
#Elmo
elmo = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2").signatures["default"]

# Provide input tensor and create embeddings
input_tensor = ["my birthday is the best day of the year"]
embeddings_tensor = elmo(tf.constant(input_tensor))["elmo"]  #, signature="default", as_dict=True)

#with tf.Session() as sess:
   # sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    #embeddings = sess.run(embeddings_tensor)
print(embeddings_tensor.shape)
print(embeddings_tensor)
```

Output:

```
(1, 9, 1024)
tf.Tensor(
[[[-0.05932237 -0.13262326 -0.12817773 ...  0.05492031  0.55205816
   -0.15840778]
  [ 0.06928141  0.28926378  0.37178952 ... -0.22100006  0.6793189
    1.0836271 ]
  [ 0.02626347  0.16981134 -0.14045191 ... -0.53703904  0.9646159
    0.7538886 ]
  ...
  [-0.09166492  0.19069327 -0.14435166 ... -0.8409722   0.3632321
   -0.41222304]
  [ 0.40042678 -0.02149609  0.38503993 ...  0.49869162  0.07260808
   -0.3582598 ]
  [ 0.10684142  0.23578405 -0.4308424  ...  0.06925966 -0.14734827
    0.13421637]]], shape=(1, 9, 1024), dtype=float32)
```

OR the same code can be run using below code above your code (by converting it into `TF 1.x`), it will execute successfully:

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
```